# BackboneJS is unable to call functions from UnderscoreJS

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-model

I am working on installing BackboneJS in my project - and it loads fine when its referenced and loaded from the HTML page. However, when backbone API is called from my main.js, then it shows an error. The error says that its unable to access an API call in Underscore.js even though UnderscoreJS is called and loaded. Here's the error as it shows in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: How are you importing the scripts?

Comment: What version of Underxscore do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I canged the CDN used to get the minified underscore file and it worked.

Here's the earlier one I had which is appears to be outdated:

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js
```

Here's the right one:

```
https://rawgithub.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore-min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

The `result` function was added in [Underscore 1.3.3](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog) and Backbone requires [at least version 1.5.0](http://backbonejs.org/#). Are you sure you comply to these requirements?

Comment: The CDN was serving an outdated version. I fixed that. Thanks though.